# Matrix won't stay on my plane

Tags: animation-nodes, parent

Hi i need help on making these cubes stay on my plane, the location part is easy to do, but the rotation only rotates on it's bounds, not the group's bounds

any way i can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Transform Matrix` node to rotate whole matrix list.

[image]

Comment: when i render it doesn't seem to want to update my plane, how do i make it update when it renders?

Comment: Not sure why. You can ask to developers:https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues